# PHP accessing protected constructor

Tags: php, constructor, protected

I know it is very uncommon to use protected methods or constructors. I have read discussions about this on SO and other sites.
The task I've got is rather simple. I have to access protected methods/constructors from my program. All attributes/methods must be declared as protected.

My code can be reduced to this. I'm basically asked to do this with the easiest/simplest way. All solutions I can think of either use some more advanced technique ("friends" etc) or a public function, which is against the rules.

Thank you.

```
     class one
        {
         protected $attribute1;
        }

        class two extends one
        {
         protected $attribute2;
         protected $attribute3;
            protected function __construct($arg1, $arg2, $arg3)  
         {
          $this->attribute1= $arg1;
          $this->attribute2= $arg2;
          $this->attribute3= $arg3;

            }
        }

$object = new two(" 1", "2", "3");
```

Comment: I don't really understand your question... PHP doesn't allows you to use the constructor (e.g. doing `$object = new two(" 1", "2", "3");`) when it is defined as protected ?

Comment: Why does the constructor have to be protected?

Comment: The question is - how do I construct an object if all contents of my classes are private?  It's one of the questions in my home assignment and I have no ideas at the moment. So I decided to make a question.

Answer (score 4):

The purpose of a private or protected constructor is to prevent the class from being instantiated from outside of the class.

You could create a public static function in the class that returns a new object, but you cannot create it directly if you want to have the constructor be protected or private.  You must have something declared as public or you cannot use the class.

Comment: Well, it seems that I found out where the problem. was. I misinterpreted the task. It's all doable if constructors are public, and attributes/methods are protected.

Comment: Yes, making a constructor private or protected has very specific uses but is not a good idea most of the time.

Comment: I made assumption that constructor needs to be protected, because attributes/methods needed to be protected. Task description didn't say anything about access zone (?) of constructors. Thanks everyone. Sorry for wasting a couple minutes of your time.